# Hangman Game - IndexError: list index out of range - It's because of my for loop on line 89 but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, list

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 89, in 
update += guesses[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

On line 89, only happens if you input a correct letter, I know it's because of the list not having a way to stop after a certain number but I don't know what to add to make that happen, I thought I knew but my mind is blank.

Code area that has error

```
update = ""
for i in range(len(word)):
  if Guess == word[i]:
    update += Guess
  else:
    update += guesses[i]
guesses = update
```

Full code: https://github.com/BUBBLEGUM846/BUBBLEGUM846/blob/main/Hangman

Comment: Did you mean `guesses[-1]` (the most recent guess added to the list of guesses) instead of `guesses[i]` (the `i`th guess, where `i` can be up to the number of letters in the word)?

Comment: `guesses` has too few elements, so `[i]` is out of range.  You haven't shown us how that list is created/updated, so we can't say any more.

Comment: @JohnGordon I left the link to the full code so you can see it there.

Comment: All relevant code should be posted directly in the question.  Posting code as an external link just means fewer people will help.

Comment: @JohnGordon I didn't realise it was relevant at the time and github is a website that *many* upload their code to so they don't have to copy and paste everything plus the code wasn't going into the code format and it looked weird so that's why I thought it would be better to upload it where other people have told me to in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i mean, you could do

```py
update = ""
for i in range(len(word)):
  try:
    if Guess == word[i]:
      update += Guess
    else:
      update += guesses[i]
  except:
    pass
guesses = update
```

its extremely crude, but it works

Comment: It fixes that problem but now when I get a word wrong my hangman isn't updating and it's not telling me if a letter is right or wrong

Comment: let me update it

Comment: ok it should work now

Comment: Yup! Thanks, this is great.